# Python product of ascii, wrong start

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

I wrote a simple script in order to check the availability of some domains, but I can't understand why it starts with `abns` not `aaaa`.

Here is the code :

```
import whois
import eventlet

from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase

f = open('4-letter.txt', 'w')

k = (''.join(x) for x in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=4))


def fetch(url):
    for x in k:
        if whois.whois(x+".ro").status == "OK":
            print(x+" bad")
        else:
            f.write(x+".ro\n")


pool = eventlet.GreenPool()

for status in pool.imap(fetch, k):  
    print(status)

f.close()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce; did you check both `4-letter.txt` and stdout (console window) for `aaaa`?

Comment: I can see that *abns.ro* is occupied. Can it be that *aaaa, aaab ... abnr* are all available and this is the first which is occupied?

Comment: Where does `url` in `fetch` get used?

Comment: Is `k` a generator? Won't it get used up in `pool.imap` and then inside `fetch` too? I don't understand the code.

Comment: I checked the txt file there is no aaaa, k is a kind of a generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the global generator `k` in this function:

```
def fetch(url):
    for x in k:
        if whois.whois(x+".ro").status == "OK":
            print(x+" bad")
        else:
            f.write(x+".ro\n")
```

But you also hand `k` to `pool.imap(fetch, k)`. So `k` is already iterated over several steps before `fetch()` is called.